# Selecting elements from a vector based on condition on another vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, subset, matrix-indexing

I want to know how to select those numbers which correspond (i.e. same position) to my pre-defined numbers.

For example, I have these vectors:

```
a = [  1 0.1   2   3 0.1 0.5   4 0.1];
b = [100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800]
```

I need to select elements from `b` which correspond to the positions of the whole numbers in `a` (1, 2, 3 and 4), so the output must be:

```
output = [1  100
          2  300
          3  400
          4  700]
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Create a logical index based on `a`,  and apply it to both `a` and `b` to get the desired result:

```
ind = ~mod(a,1); % true for integer numbers
output = [a(ind); b(ind)].'; % build result
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the intention is not clear, creating indexing to the matrix is the solution

My solution is

```
checkint = @(x) ~isinf(x) & floor(x) == x % It's very fast in a big array
[a(checkint(a))' b(checkint(a))']
```

The key here is creating the index to `a` and `b` for which it is a logical vector to the integer values in `a`. This function `checkint` does a good job checking integer.

Other approaches to check integer could be

```
checkint = @(x)double(uint64(x))==x % Slower but it works fine
```

or

```
checkint = @(x) mod(x,1) == 0 % Slowest, but it's robust and better for understanding what's going on
```

or

```
checkint = @(x) ~mod(x,1) % Slowest, treat 0 as false
```

It's been discussed in many other threads.

Comment: Nice comparison of methods. But using the fastest approach is sort of muted by computing it twice. Better save the result of `checkint` in a temporary variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
round(x) == x ----> x is a whole number
round(x) ~= x ----> x is not a whole number
```

```
round(2.4) = 2 ------> round(2.4) ~= 2.4 --> 2.4 is not a whole number
round(2) = 2 --------> round(2)   == 2 ----> 2 is a whole number
```

**Following same logic**

```
a = [  1 0.1   2   3 0.1 0.5   4 0.1];
b = [100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 700];
iswhole = (round(a) == a);
output = [a(iswhole); b(iswhole)]
```

Result:

```
output =

     1     2     3     4
   100   300   400   700
```

Comment: `!=` is not valid Matlab syntax; use `~=` instead

Answer (score 1):

we can generate logical index based on a using fix() function

```
ind = (a==fix(a));
output= [a(ind); b(ind)]'
```